# Css class nesting and grouping

Tags: css, class, grouping, nested

What is the difference between

```
#id .A.B x {  }
#id .A .B  y { }
```

in CSS file?

Both A and B are classes.
x and y are some tags

Does the spacing between .A and .B have any significance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case, it references an element that has both A and B as classes:

```
<div class="A B"></div>
```

The second is an element with class A that has an element with class B nested inside:

```
<div class="A">
  <div class="B"></div>
</div>
```